# How to retrieve data from Autosuggestbox with SQlite?

Tags: sqlite, uwp, windows-phone, autosuggest

I created a SQLite database but the issue is when type it blocks and i don´t get any data and go away app. It´s the first time that i use Database. I paste a code fragment.

```
Public NotInheritable Class METARTAF
Inherits Page
Dim dbpath As String
Dim conn As SQLiteConnection

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    'Ubicación de la base de datos
    dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "airportsdb.sqlite3")
    'Conexión a la base de datos
    conn = New SQLiteConnection(New WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbpath)
End Sub

Private Sub AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(sender As AutoSuggestBox, args As AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs)
    Dim result = conn.Query(Of airports)("select * from airports where name ").FirstOrDefault()
    If args.Reason = AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput Then
        If sender.Text.Length > 1 Then
            sender.ItemsSource = result
        End If
    Else
        sender.ItemsSource = "No results..."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind

1. Use the Async version of SQLite, it should help with the blocking
2. Or even better, load all the airports you search to a list in memory when the page is displayed and search them in this list instead of directly calling SQLite

Answer (score 0):

If you're using synchronus SQLite apis you can wrap your Query method in Task.Run. Wrapping your logic in Run will let your code run in the background thread. **Since TextChanged handler is running in the UI thread any long running operation you do will block the UI thread and will eventually freeze the app.**

**As Igor suggested, you can use async APIs of SQLite.** Those APIs will run in the background thread. Only thing you should consider is not updating your ItemsSource directly. Any operation performed in the background thread update the UI thread will cause an exception.

If your 'airports' table doesn't have big-sized data you should fetch them to the memory and keep it there and when you want to query it, instead of going to SQLite everytime you should get them from memory

Setting your ItemsSource directly will not update the view. You should really look up for ObservableCollection. If you want to update your view when you fetch data, **you must set your ItemsSource to null before you set it to your data.**